# Change Registry Value Command Line

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-registry, batch

Is there a way to set a registry value with a command line *without* using a .reg file to import it?

I've looked over the `reg` and `regedit.exe` command line options, and it doesn't look like there's a way to do something like this...

```
reg update [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup]
"SourcePath"="X:\\"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup" /v SourcePath /t REG_SZ /d "X:\\"
```

Add `/f` if you want to skip prompting for a possible overwrite.

Comment: Thanks, guess I didn't look close enough at that value